# How to fix google ads api unathorized error when using service account

Tags: c#, google-api, google-ads-api

I'm doing azure function which should regularly get ad reports from Google Ads API and save it to CSV.
Copying code from Google documentation left me with this

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 22 12 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        RunRequest(new GoogleAdsClient(new GoogleAdsConfig() { 
            DeveloperToken = "/*token*/",
            OAuth2Mode = OAuth2Flow.SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
            OAuth2PrnEmail = "/*service account email*/",
            OAuth2SecretsJsonPath = "/*service account json*/"
        }), "/*client id*/", log);
    }

public static void RunRequest(GoogleAdsClient client, string customerId, ILogger log)
    {
        // Get the GoogleAdsService.
        GoogleAdsServiceClient googleAdsService = client.GetService(
            Services.V5.GoogleAdsService);

        // Create the query.
        string query = @"/*request*/";

        try
        {
            // Issue a search request.
            googleAdsService.SearchStream(customerId, query,
                delegate (SearchGoogleAdsStreamResponse resp)
                {
                    using var writer = new StreamWriter($"reports\\report{DateTime.Now}.csv");
                    using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    csv.WriteRecords(Report.BuildReports(resp.Results));
                }
            );
        }
        catch (GoogleAdsException e)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Failure:");
            log.LogInformation($"Message: {e.Message}");
            log.LogInformation($"Failure: {e.Failure}");
            log.LogInformation($"Request ID: {e.RequestId}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Executing this code gives me an exception with this content:

> "Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated", Detail="Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22)

As I understand I don't need OAuth2 access token when using service account. How to fix this problem, what am I missing?

Comment: You need to be authorized with Oauth2 to access that method.    Where exactly does it state in the documentation that this api supports service accounts?  Can you give us a link to the documentation you are following?

Comment: @DalmTo basing on this https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-dotnet . This repository is linked as example here https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs  <-- dead link do you have a live one?

Comment: From what i can see here they only have Installed application and Web application samples what makes you think service accounts are supported? https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Authentication

Comment: @DalmTo strang, link works on my mobile and doesn't work on my pc. Anyway, https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-dotnet/blob/master/src/App.config pretty clearly states the possibility of using service account

Comment: I think you should try and contact the authors of the library and ask for assistance.   Without being to access any documentation on this api its hard to help.   I can tell you that the issue is that you are not properly applying any authorization to your request.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [authorization section](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts) of the reference documentation, you can only use service accounts if you have a G Suite (now called Google Workspace) domain.

You'll need to set up [domain-wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106) for the given OAuth client and then do a [user impersonation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/dotnet/oauth-service) for a G Suite account that has access to the Google Ads accounts you need to work with.